# Adding a graphic to the beginning of an existing (.nb) notebook file

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

I want to prepend graphics (as generated by `Plot`) to an existing .nb notebook file, each new addition being placed as a new cell at the top of the notebook page. But I cannot figure out how to do it. Yes I know the function `PutAppend`, but this function has some problems:

- the added graphics are not shown as graphics in the notebook, but as input code;
- it puts the new content at the end of the file, not at the beginning;
- the newly added part does not exist as a separate cell.

So `PutAppend` may not fit here. How then can it be done?

__

Edit: I hope to do it without opening the notebook file in question and to save the file automatically after adding graphics.

Comment: I can promise you that you don't want to do this at the string level. Load the notebook with `NotebookImport`. Insert `Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@yourPlot, "Input"]` and the first position. `Export` that `Notebook`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your notebook is called `nb`, e.g.

```
file = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", 
    "English", "System", "ExampleData", "document.nb"}];
nb = NotebookOpen[file];
```

then evaluate this to stick a plot at the start:

```
SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook]
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], "Output"]]
```

**Edit**

As per comments this can be automated so that the notebook is not visible (below I have saved to a new file so as not to overwrite the built in file used in the example):

```
file = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", 
    "English", "System", "ExampleData", "document.nb"}];
nb = NotebookOpen[file, Visible -> False];
SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], "Output"]];
NotebookSave[nb, FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "saved.nb"}]]
NotebookClose[nb]
```

If you wanted to add the same graphic to multiple files you can make a function from the above:

```
addGraphic[file_, graphic_Cell] := Module[{nb},

  nb = NotebookOpen[file, Visible -> False];
  SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook];
  NotebookWrite[nb, graphic];
  NotebookSave[nb];
  NotebookClose[nb]
  ]

addGraphic[#, 
   Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], "Output"]] & /@ files
```

Comment: Thank you. This requires that the file be opened first; I'll adopt this method if a better method is not available. Is it possible to do it without opening that document file and to save the file automatically, as `PutAppend` can? That is what I had in mind originally, but I failed to express it clearly in my post.

Comment: @User18 add `NotebookSave` and `NotebookClose` and it is easily automated. You can add `Visible->False` if you do not want to see the notebook open. Anyway i have to go now.

Comment: Valuable answer; thanks a lot!

Comment: That function is great indeed.

Answer (score 3):

```
test = Export[
   FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.nb"}],
   Notebook[{Cell[BoxData["1+1"]]}]
];
```

Alternatively:

```
Export[
  test
, Insert[
    Import[test]
  , Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Graphics@Disk[], "Output"]
  , {{1, 1}}
  ]
];
```

and check:

```
NotebookOpen@test
```

Comment: This is nice too. Thanks!